# Debugging Help: C++ error

Tags: c++, debugging

I am getting this error:

```
SortedList.cpp:197: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
```

This is the code:

```
197    Listnode *SortedList::copyList(Listnode *L) {
198        Listnode *current = L;
199
200        Listnode *copy = new Listnode;
201        copy->student = new Student(*current->student);
202        copy->next = NULL;
203
204        Listnode *head = copy;
205
206        current = current->next;
207        while (current != NULL) {
208            copy = copy->next = new Listnode;
209            copy->student = new Student(*current->student);
210            copy->next = NULL;
211        }
212        return head;
213    }
```

This is the Listnode:

```
struct Listnode {
    Student *student;
    Listnode *next;
};
Listnode *head;
```

Not sure what I am supposed to do. I have a constructor and destructor implemented already if needed to be viewed. Any insight as to what the problem possibly is would be helpful.

Comment: Where is `Listnode` defined in `SortedList.cpp` or its own header file ?

Comment: In a SortedList.h file. It is a private member of a SortedList class

Comment: then you must refer to it as  SortedList::Listnode  in the function signature

Comment: what exactly would the function signature look like then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments  `ListNode` appears to be a nested class you need to use the following :
 `SortedList::Listnode *SortedList::copyList(SortedList::Listnode *L)` 
   also you may need to make it `public` if `copyList` is  public.